# File download does not start when invoke or execute an URL

Tags: c#

If anyone load this url https://de.visiblealpha.com/links/80488d55-ae41-4def-9452-bae3ac2e2b06 into browser then a excel file start download. so when i invoke the same url by **HttpWebRequest** then excel file does not start download. this code example i tried.

```
string address = "https://de.visiblealpha.com/links/80488d55-ae41-4def-9452-bae3ac2e2b06";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadString(address);
}
```

again i tried this one too.

```
string url = "https://de.visiblealpha.com/links/80488d55-ae41-4def-9452-bae3ac2e2b06";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but failed to reach my goal. code successfully executed but no excel file start downloading which i am trying to achieve.

when i tried to load this url https://de.visiblealpha.com/links/80488d55-ae41-4def-9452-bae3ac2e2b06 into webbrowser control then also saw same problem no excel file start download. here is code which i tried.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://de.visiblealpha.com/links/80488d55-ae41-4def-9452-bae3ac2e2b06");
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

i just do not understand why excel file is not getting download when invoke or execute the same very url.

so please some one tell me what i need to do as a result the moment i will execute the url excel file will start downloading in client pc.

please share some working code example.

Comment: my guess is that the link is using javascript to trigger download. If thats the case you would need to read their js code and find out how they are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DownloadString returns the contents into a variable aka in memory.  A file will not get saved on the system.  If that is what you intended, there's a small change you need to make in your code:

```
string address = "https://de.visiblealpha.com/links/80488d55-ae41-4def-9452-bae3ac2e2b06";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string contents = client.DownloadString(address);
}
```

The variable "contents" will contain html of the URL in your question.  If you want it as a file, then I you need to use DownloadFile method instead.  The spreadsheet itself is a different URL.

There's an example at the end of this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: contents variable just hold the html string not excel file content. just load the url which i have mention here in browser then must notice that when page load then a excel file also start downloading. just tell me how could i start download of that excel file invoking the above url?

Comment: The webpage uses javascript to push the download automatically.  The javascript won't run using WebClient.   The URL to actually download the excel spreadsheet is not the same as in your question.   I haven't been able to figure out the exact url.   But you can follow the example in the link I gave you using the correct URL to get the spreadsheet through C# code.